# Python sorting with square as key

Tags: python, list

Saw some code on a book and just cannot follow it, even try to decipher by run step-by-step and it's still Greek to me... (on 2nd Mon. journey)
(I kind of know each part, eg. `range` or `sorted` or `lambda`- except putting together)

```
sorted(range(-3,4), key=lambda x: x*x)
```

Output:

```
[0,-1,1,-2,2,-3,3]
```

Comment: It's the numbers from -3 to +3, sorted according to their squares (which for real numbers is like sorting by their absolute value).

Comment: Great question. Learned some Python details today.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it - I'm still not able to get it?  Sorry.

Comment: It's a good question - there are some `magic` here - need some expert's view.

Answer (score 3):

```py
sorted(range(-3,4), key=lambda x: x*x)
```

Try to do it step by step.
Let's start with `range`, `range` here will provide numbers `-3`, `-2`, `-1`, `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`.

`sorted` then runs on each of these items and uses the function provided in the `key` parameter. Each of these items is passed on the `x` parameter of the `lambda`. The `lambda` then handles this `x` (represented as the number in the `range`) and performs some operations, in your case, it just gets the square of the number `x`. The square value then gets returned and the `sorted` function uses this returned square value in comparing in ascending order (remember that `sorted` arranges the list in ascending order unless specified as `reverse=True`).

The purpose of the `key` function is to only tell how to compare each item in the iterable/list passed. But it does not affect the final list of elements that will be returned. It will still use the passed list. So these values `-3`, `-2`, `-1`, `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3` will be the elements of the returned list by the `sorted` function, only arranged in accordance with the `key` parameter.

Hope it helps and makes sense.

Comment: But how can 0 is before -1, if that's the ascending order by default?

Comment: @annie2020, as I said, look at the function in the `key` parameter in determining the sorting order, `0 * 0 = 0`, while `-1 * -1 = 1`, and if you'll compare their square  `0 < 1` (`0` is less than `1`), hence making `0` appear before `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

`range` is defined as `range(start, stop, step)` and the stop parameter is not included.

`sorted` defined as `sorted(iterable, key=key, reverse=reverse)` seems to work like this:

The original input values are outputted but sorted by a key, in this case by their square. The square converts the negative values into positive ones, then sorting is applied and finally, the original values are returned in order.

Tested this on the command line:

```
print(sorted(range(-3,4)))
# [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]

print(sorted(range(-3,4), key=lambda x: x*x))
# [0, -1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3]
```

The [Python Docs about sorting](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html); it says for both `sorted()` (and also `sort()`) the sort is **stable**:

> Sorts are guaranteed to be stable. That means that when multiple records have the same key, their original order is preserved.

Comment: Not to criticize - but I don't believe you have answered the question - how the `results` has evolved to the  strangeness.  (it's seem that's the question itself)

Comment: I don't see strangeness after my tests. Sorry, but the tests show that the original values are returned, but sorted based on the defined key.

Comment: Let me try one more time - how the `sorted (...)` gave out the results - as [0,-1,1...] Thank you!

Comment: I know how each part work very well... It just become elusive and magic then when 'glue all together' . Sorry for my dumb question...

Comment: The range defines -3 to +3 and these original values are returned. The lambda in the key converts them to positive values. Honestly, not sure what you are missing. The sorting is based on 0, 1,1, 4, 4, 9 (square), your statement then returns 0, -1, 1, -2, 2, -3 as these are the values you defined by the range. Maybe just hard to explain :)

Comment: If lambda did convert each to positive num. then there should be no negative numbers? I think it's getting closer...but something is still not `click` yet.  Much appreciated your patience 

Comment: As said, the original values are returned, I cannot tell you more about the magic, and why and how -1 and 1 and -2 and 2 are exactly differentiated. Sorry!

Comment: That's what got me into the `puzzle`!!

Comment: Very interesting question, but maybe this is a topic like true and false in Ruby and Java Script. It needs some Python code maintainers to answer the question about the real magic, I guess. Over and out :)

Comment: It seems to be dependend on / related to the order of values.

Comment: @annie2020 the numbers aren't converted by the lambda, it's only used to determine the sorting *key* and thus the order.  And the one secret left out of this answer is that Python sorts are stable, meaning if the keys are equal the elements with the same key retain their original order with respect to each other.  That's why the negative numbers come first.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks for the hint, found it now in the documentation I linked to before, updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

It works like this:b

The `range` function returns the value `[-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]`.

Now the confusing piece, the key argument, calls `lambda` for each of the values to be sorted and **instead use those value to sort them**.

That means the list was **sorted by their square** `[9, 4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 9] and not by their actual number as returned by the range function.

For example:

```
sorted(range(-3,4), key=lambda x: x*-1)
```

would return `[3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3]`